# How I can create 3 subscripts after a variable?

Tags: mathjax

I have

```
\over E_max - E_min
```

but it doesn't display all of them as a subscript, just the first m after the E_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the subscripts in curly braces so that all three characters are included.

```
\over E_{max} - E_{min}
```

Comment: It doesn't work : $$ Normalized(e_i) = {E_i - E_{min} \over E_{max} - E_{min} } $$

Comment: @Bogo Where are you doing this? It appears to be working on Math.SE. http://i.stack.imgur.com/taIrV.png

Comment: in markdownpad2 - the problem is probably there. Thanks for the hint